# Unable to edit file UNIX

Tags: unix, chmod

I am trying to edit a file in vi editor - and when I try to save the changes it says READ ONLY. Even when I try to do a chmod I get an error saying I cannot do so.

I have logged in Unix using a personal ID and not a service one

Comment: You should ask your admin for the root password. Then you're 31337 and can chmod 777 EVERYTHING, thus solving the problem forevermore.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the answer - not sure why my post is downvoted by others cos I have a question and am not an expert in Unix

Comment: Good grief... do not follow my advice, that was perhaps a poorly judged joke. You should try sudo if you have the correct substitute users in your settings. If not, you may have to contact an admin

Comment: Anyways I learnt something new - sudo

Comment: Although if your admin is gullible enough to give you root... The world is your oyster.

Comment: @Nidhin_toms: While I wouldn't down-vote your answer (and haven't), I would tell you that your question is not _programmming_-related and thus belongs on a different StackExchange site, such as http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't owner of this file. You need to `sudo vim` with an owner user.

Comment: I could su to my service ID and I could execute the file with no problem - how do I do the same with my personal ID ?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening editing the file in vim using: `sudo vim <filename>`

Some people also recommend adding this to your .vimrc file so you can open the file without `sudo` then write to it anyway using :`w!!`

```
" Sudo to write
cnoremap w!! w !sudo tee % >/dev/null
```

Comment: What is the difference between vim and vi

Comment: Vim is the "improved" Vi. In practical terms they're the same. In either case, just use `sudo` in front of vim or vi to open the file.

Comment: One caveat: Some platforms - e.g., Ubuntu - have only a `vi`, not a `vim` executable _in the path_ (even though `vi` may be a _symlink to_ `vim`).